# NotePad++ Add space in between a word and number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to do add space between a word and a number in NotePad++. For example:

- Number1234567
- Numer2345678

to

- Number 1234567
- Number 2345678

Comment: how is it related to java?

Comment: To add a space in a text editor, move the cursor to the place where you want to add the space, using either the arrow keys on your keyboard or by clicking there with your mouse, then press the space bar in your keyboard.

Comment: Use `indexof()` to search the index, where the numbers start. The search has to have the regex `[0-9]+`

Comment: - Andreas It takes too long

Comment: @JernejK I didn't know NotePad++ had an `indexof()`. I know Java does, but NotePad++?

Comment: @Jordan It takes too long to add *one* space? Wow are you impatient. Or maybe your question is written wrong and you mean something entirely different from what it is currently saying.

Comment: @Andreas NotePad++ is an editor, same as Eclipse. If you are asking for a Java solution, I gave you one example how to do it. Java is the programming language.

Comment: @Jordan There's regex based find and replace available in notepad++. Use that.

Comment: @Andreas I specifically asked for something that would space it out doesn't mean i'm impatient. If you can't answer the question please do not reply.

Comment: Check this link - http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Jordan I can answer the question. In fact I just did. The issue was whether you can actually ask the question the right way. Apparently not.

Comment: Notepad++ is irrelevant if you are coding in Java. Are you looking for a Java based solution?

Comment: @Andreas He clearly wanted to replace multiple (possibly thousands) of strings, not just one or two. No need to be rude about it.

Comment: @Jordan I gave you an up out of pity for you for so many downvotes, but now I took it back, for this: *If you can't answer the question please do not reply*. Now look who actually gave you the working solution. So, careful what you say.

Comment: @kchinger If you look at my first comment, you'll see that I perfectly answered the question, as it is written. I was fairly certain that it was not the answer that was desired, so I wrote it as a comment and not an answer, but it truly answers the question. I then commented that the question is worded wrong, and OP then accuses me of not being able to answer the question, when in truth I had. I don't like being accused like that, when it is actually the question that is wrong (unclear), not my answer. Sorry that I answered rude with rude, but I won't take it back.

Answer (score 6):

In NotePad++:

1. Press `ctrl+h` to open the "Replace" dialog.
2. Type `([a-z])([0-9])` in the "Find what:" field.
3. Type `\1 \2` in the "Replace with:" field.
4. Select "Regular expression" in the "Search Mode" box.
5. Make sure "Match case" is unchecked.
6. Make sure "Wrap around" is checked.
7. Make sure "In selection" is unchecked.
8. Click "Replace All".

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why Java is on there, but to do regex replacement in Notepad++ select the regex options (obviously). The find should be `Number(\d+)`. The replace should be `Number \1`. Backslash 1 is the first matched group from the find regex. (\d+) is a grouping that matches at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Find what field, type: `([0-9])([A-z])`
2. In the Replace with field, type: `\1 \2`
3. Select "Regular expression" in the "Search Mode" box.
4. Make sure "Match case" is unchecked.
5. Make sure "Wrap around" is checked.
6. Make sure "In selection" is unchecked.
7. Click "Replace All".

Note: If you want to add any character after number like dots or commas... 
In the Replace with field, type: `\1.\2`

Comment: Why did you copy @Andreas answer? with an error, `[A-z]` matches more than letters, it includes `left opening bracket, back slash, right closing bracket, caret cirumflex, underscore, backtick`, see http://table-ascii.com/